# Return value from dynamic linked server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to return a value from a dynamic linked server stored procedure.

```
--storedprocedure on the remote linked server
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPTEST]
@DocNumOut VARCHAR(20) output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @DocNumOut=1;
    RETURN @DocNumOut
END
```

On the local server, how can I retrieve the value of `@DocNumOut`? I have trial many combination using `EXEC`, `openquery`, `EXEC sp_executesql`, but none can return the value into my local variable, `@DocNumberOUT`.

```
--local server
DECLARE @DocNumberOUT as int;
DECLARE @SQLCMD AS VARCHAR(2000)='EXEC LinkedServer.MyDB.dbo.SPTEST'
EXEC @DocNumberOUT= sp_executesql @SQLCMD
--Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
```

Comment: Does this not work `DECLARE @DocNumberOUT varchar(20); EXEC LinkedServer.MyDB.dbo.SPTEST @DocNumberOUT = @DocNumberOUT` Why do you have `RETURN` and an `OUTPUT` parameter for the same information anyway? And if it is an integer why is the parameter declared `varchar(20)`? If it might not be an integer you can't `RETURN` it anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OUTPUT parameter on your Stored Procedure and don't use the return value.

Use the proper data type. Don't use `varchar` for everything. Since you assigned an integer to the variable, declare it as `integer`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPTEST]
    @DocNumOut INT output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @DocNumOut=1;
END
```

On the calling side, the error message is telling you that `@SQLCMD` should declare as `NVARCHAR`. Using `sp_executesql` is the right choice. But you should also define the parameters and pass in the variable also. `@DocNumOut` is the name of the parameter that you defined in `SPTEST`. `@DocNumberOUT` is your local variable

```
DECLARE @DocNumberOUT as int;

DECLARE @SQLCMD AS NVARCHAR(2000);

SET @SQLCMD = 'EXEC [LinkedServer].[MyDB].[dbo].[SPTEST] @DocNumOut = @DocNumberOUT OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLCMD, N'@DocNumberOUT INT OUTPUT', @DocNumberOUT OUTPUT

SELECT @DocNumberOUT
```